# route /$id in livewire cant access data

Tags: laravel, laravel-livewire

ok i want to create route like showing data in another page like this

> http://localhost:8000/uraian/1

my route like this

`Route::get('/uraian/{id}', [PengadaanController::class, 'uraian'])->name('uraian');`

i can access this and its normal . now its my livewire function

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Livewire;

use Livewire\WithPagination;

use App\Models\Kegi;

use App\Models\Uraian;

use Livewire\Component;

class UraianLw extends Component

{

    use WithPagination;
       public $uraianid ,$kegiatan_id ,$kode_rekening ,$uraian ,$anggaran ;




    public function render($id)

    {

        $kegiatan = Kegi::findOrFail($id);// here the problem

        $newid = $kegiatan->id ;

        

        return view('livewire.uraian-lw',[

            'uraian' => Uraian::where('id' ,$newid)->where('uraian', 'like', '%'.$this->search.'%')->paginate(10)

        ]);

    }
}
```

and have error

> Unable to resolve dependency [Parameter #0 [  $id ]] in class App\Http\Livewire\Uraian

how can solved this problem ?

#update its my blade

```
<x-app-layout>
<x-slot name="header">
    <h2 class="font-semibold text-xl text-gray-800 leading-tight">
        {{ __('Dashboard') }} 
    </h2>
</x-slot>


     @livewire('uraian-lw')
           
    

</x-app-layout>
```

Comment: add your `PengadaanController` code as well  or where your calling this component .?

Comment: i need to use controller ?

Comment: you added `Route::get('/uraian/{id}', [PengadaanController::class, 'uraian'])->name('uraian');` here that controller right .?

Comment: right , i add it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you should use this

```php
<x-app-layout>
<x-slot name="header">
    <h2 class="font-semibold text-xl text-gray-800 leading-tight">
        {{ __('Dashboard') }} 
    </h2>
</x-slot>


     @livewire('uraian-lw',['id' => Route::current()->parameter('id')]) <----------------- pass id from blade
           
    

</x-app-layout>
```

#### App\Http\Livewire\UraianLw.php

```php
<?php

use Livewire\Component;
use App\Models\Kegi;
use App\Models\Uraian;


class UraianLw extends Component

{

    use WithPagination;
    public $uraianid, $kegiatan_id, $kode_rekening, $uraian, $anggaran, $newid;


    public function mount($id)
    {
        $kegiatan = Kegi::findOrFail($id);
        $this->newid = $kegiatan->id;
    }

    public function render()

    {
        return view('livewire.uraian-lw', [

            'uraian' => Uraian::where('id', $this->newid)->where('uraian', 'like', '%' . $this->search . '%')->paginate(10)

        ]);
    }
}
```

Comment: ok i see . but how i can use this $newid like in my render ?

Comment: wait i will try

Comment: i follow all you step but still have error Unable to resolve dependency [Parameter #0 [ <required> $id ]] in class App\Http\Livewire\UraianLw

Comment: i m not at $id on render function

Comment: @AdhikMulat upidated my answer check it

Comment: ok its solved sir , i think my problem is passing this $id in blade . i need to create on my controller because i still using controller not only Livewire

Comment: @AdhikMulat yes